# Multithread alternative to accumarray

Tags: multithreading, matlab, vectorization, accumarray

I am using `accumarray()` to create a 3D array from a list of xyz coordinates `PointCoors` and their respective values `PointValues` like this:

```
Stack=accumarray([PointCoors(:,1),PointCoors(:,2),PointCoors(:,3)],PointValues,...
  StackSize,@max,uint16(0));
```

However I found out that `accumarray()` does not multithread (don't see why it shouldn't) and as a result of this the computation of this step takes too long.

Is there an alternative to `accumarray()` that can take advantage of multiple cores?

Thank you

Comment: If you have a compatible GPU, and Parallel Computing Toolbox, there's an implementation of `accumarray` that runs on the GPU.

Comment: Do you mean at the File Exchange? I only found one that needs some rework to be used like I do in my example...

Comment: No, I mean the product from the MathWorks: http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/

Comment: I see now... "UNKNOWN_CUDA_ ERROR"... sadly the GPU doesn't seem to be compatible. Thanks for the tip anyway.